# Can't figure out how to "bind" values together in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So I need to create an array that looks like this

```
var cols = [
      ["#1ABC9C", "0%"],
      ["#1ABC9C", "33.3%"],
      ["#EC7063", "33.3%"],
      ["#EC7063", "66.6%"],
      ["#3498DB", "66.6%"],
      ["#3498DB", "100%"]
];
```

Now here's what I'm able to generate so far

```
["#000", 0, "#000", 33.333333333333336, "#4AF2A1", 33.333333333333336, "#4AF2A1", 33.333333333333336, "#FC4831", 33.333333333333336, "#FC4831", 100]
```

What I've done here is get the second value in the array, and added a 0, since that's what the starting point should be, I've also done the same for the last value, but set that as 100.

Here's what I get when I "generate" the values that should be in the array

```
33.3, 66.6, 100
```

Now what I need to do is replace the second array with the values I get, to make it look like the first. Any ideas? The values `33.3, 66.6, 100` are dynamic, so they could be `25,50,75,100` or whatever else, but they're all integers. Which means that the final array could look like this

```
var cols = [
        ["#1ABC9C", "0%"],
        ["#1ABC9C", "25%"],
        ["#EC7063", "25%"],      
        ["#009DFF", "50%"],
        ["#009DFF", "50%"],
        ["#EC7063", "75%"],
        ["#3498DB", "75%"],
        ["#3498DB", "100%"]
];
```

Comment: What you do now is adding values to an array. What you should do is add a array to a array. So instead of pushing the RGB, then push the percentage. You should push a array. Like cols.push(["#1ABC9C", "0%"]);

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure what your input looks like; I assume it's an array with just the colors? See if my answer is what you're after.

Comment: If you include examples of both input and output, it's easier to understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will take a 1-dimensional array of strings representing the colors, and return a 2-dimensional array with the colors and the appropriate percentages with one decimal, the way you described. Check the console in the developer tools in your browser for the output.

```js
function colDistr(input) {
    var result = [], step = 0;
    for (i in input) {
        if (i % 2) step++;
        var perc = Math.floor(step * 2000 / input.length) / 10;
        result.push([input[i], perc + "%"]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(colDistr(["#1ABC9C","#1ABC9C","#EC7063","#EC7063","#3498DB","#3498DB"]));
```

If the input is an array that only contains each color once, this becomes:

```js
function colDistr(input) {
    var result = [], step = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length * 2; i++) {
        if (i % 2) step++;
        var perc = Math.floor(step * 1000 / input.length) / 10;
        result.push([input[i - step], perc + "%"]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(colDistr(["#1ABC9C","#EC7063","#3498DB"]));
```

Comment: So far so good, just one more question. How do I duplicate them? I'd get a list like `#009DFF, #FFF, #000`. So how do I get it to `#009DFF,#009DFF, #FFF,#FFF,#000,#000`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that part of the question, I thought the doubles were just an example. I guess it could be easily done in one go, let me see...

Comment: Just a minor tweak, the function now duplicates the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ary = ["#000", 0, "#000", 33.333333333333336, "#4AF2A1", 33.333333333333336, "#4AF2A1", 33.333333333333336, "#FC4831", 33.333333333333336, "#FC4831", 100];
var res = [];

for (i = 0; i < ary.length; i+=2) { 
  res.push([ ary[i], Math.round(ary[i + 1]) + '%' ]);
}

console.log(res);
```

Output:

```
[ [ '#000', '0%' ],
  [ '#000', '33%' ],
  [ '#4AF2A1', '33%' ],
  [ '#4AF2A1', '33%' ],
  [ '#FC4831', '33%' ],
  [ '#FC4831', '100%' ] ]
```

This is quite simple - we use a `for` loop to loop through the array. For each iteration we take two values from the array and push them to the results. The `i` iteration counter is increased by two for each iteration instead of the standard `i++`.

```
Math.round(ary[i + 1])
```

Rounds the number to the closest integer.

Comment: That's strange. I did [this](http://pastebin.com/RE4csrEa), and I end up getting [this](http://i.imgur.com/mddJ3AS.png)

Comment: What is strange? That's the exact same output.

Comment: Now I see. What my initial question was how would I get the percentages in the array, not structuring the array. I need to get the values I generated into the array, as stated in the question. @SebastianNette

Comment: Well, maybe next time try actually formulating your question properly and be upfront with your requirements and what your input is.